# How to change the behaviour of 'find' method for any object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

My understanding is that the find method for any rails object will expect the id column of that object. But I want to find a row of that table/object using another column of that table. How do I do that ?

For example I have userstats model as follows:

```
create_table "userstats", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "no_of_wts"
  t.integer  "no_of_wtb"
  t.integer  "wts_reputation"
  t.integer  "wtb_reputation"
  t.integer  "overall_reputation"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I want to find an instance of userstat model using the user_id (my foreign key to user model) and not using the default unique key of userstat model.

Any suggestions?

I'm using Rails 3.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do things like

```
Person.find_by_user_name
Person.find_all_by_last_name
```

docs at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

There is a really old Railscast... not sure if all the details remain the same, but can get you introduced to Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/2-dynamic-find-by-methods

Answer (score 0):

For your problem:

```
UserStat.find_all_by_user_id(5)
```

Some other examples of find():

```
UserStat.find_all_by_wts_reputation_and_wtb_reputation(1,2)
UserStat.find(:all, :conditions => { :no_of_wtb=> 5 })
```